# Chef/Ruby How to modify same file in different hosts?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I need to modify one file in 20 different nodes. Problem here is that all the files are different in lenght an number of rows and values on those nodes.
So i need to modify those files with new one created but problem is that some unique data should remain in old files too.
How should I implement this on nodes by overwriting existing file with new one with remaining some unique data. In this case it will be different host name.
I need to do this using Chef and Ruby.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Use a template, ensure it will render as expected for all nodes. Jet the tour at https://learn.chef.io

Comment: Thanks, will try to look into templates and  find something useful.

Comment: Also, maybe is it possible to open that file overwrite it . and for the first in place where should be unique fqdn hostname insert just word fqdn and save the file. After it change  in file text "fqdn" with specific hostname of current host. I am absolutely new in this so i dont know if it will be possible.

Comment: It is possible, but it's usually a nightmare to do 'modify' one line of a file instead of managing the whole file in mid term. It's likely to break because the cases are not handled properly. Really,  look at the template resource, it should be enough to render a complete file with correct parameter,  specially if you're new, take the tutorial at lean.chef.io, this will help getting on the road. You may have a look at slack for help too, see http://learn.chef.io/community (quite quiet on WE but easier to talk)

Comment: Thank you for your insights, will try to complete tutorial first and use template.

Comment: I am to stupid for this I think. I tried to find information but i just found  info how to overwrite existing file with new info something like below. But i cant find anything how to do that txt file would have automaticly added fqdn in specific part of file file which will be different in other nodes.               file "/etc/file_name" do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode 0755
  content ::File.open("/home/user/file_name").read
  action :create
end

Comment: Add.samples input to your question. We can't guess what you're after...